# How to speed up database operations?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

What can we use to reduce the time taken to get data from the database using Entity Framework? sny suggestion with caching or any other way?

Comment: You could write a stored procedure and use Database.SqlQuery to pass the result directly into your model. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Comment: **(1)** request only the columns that you ***really*** need - and **(2)** request only the rows that you ***really*** need. I.e. use a proper `SELECT (list-of-columns)` with a minimal list of columns, and use a proper `WHERE` clause to load only rows really needed. And also: index your tables based on your access patterns

Comment: First of all, find out where the bottlenecks are. Use `EXPLAIN PLAN` queries to understand cost and then create indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you check the tracking options (especially .AsNoTracking) provided by the EF.

A sneak peek to begin your research:

> When we use function AsNoTracking() we are explicitly telling Entity Framework that the entities are not tracked by the context. This can be especially useful when retrieving large amounts of data from your data store. If you want to make changes to un-tracked entities however, you must remember to attach them before calling SaveChanges.